# matplotlib cutsom style sheet: format dates with new line character

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to change how dates are formatted on my matplotlib figures so that the month and date are on a separate line from the hour and minute. I believe this should be done with a new line character. I also want to include this format rule in a [custom style sheet](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) `my_style.mplstyle` file to set this and other rcparams automatically so that all my figures have the same style without rewriting code in all my scripts.

In my `my_style.mplstyle` file, I have this formatting instruction for the dates (note the new line character):

```
date.autoformatter.hour    : %b %d\n%H:%M
```

When I load the style sheet and make a plot with dates on the x axis, it displays the `\n` as text rather than recognizing it as a new line character.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('my_style')
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
DATES = pd.date_range(datetime(2019, 1, 1), datetime(2019, 1, 2), 6)
plt.plot(DATES, range(len(DATES)))
```

[image]

I can get the desired outcome if I use the manual method to change the date formats directly in my code:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b %d\n%H:%M')
plt.plot(DATES, range(len(DATES)))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
```

[image]

**I realize I can just use the second method, but I want to know if there is a method I'm missing to let my custom style sheet recognize the new line character.**

Comment: Seems like a bug. You can file it at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues

Comment: Thanks. I submitted a bug report. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15813. Looks like it isn't currently possible to use a new line character in the style sheet, but maybe someday it will be possible.

Comment: Until the issue in the bug report mentioned above is addressed in matplotlib, it is not possible to specify a new line character in the style sheet. Instead of using the "brute force, manual method" described in the question, you can just set the rcParam at the beginning of the script which will apply the formatting to all the functions without using the `DateFormatter`. For instance, do this...

`plt.rcParams['date.autoformatter.day'] = '%b %d\n%H:%M'` or 
`plt.rcParams['date.autoformatter.hour'] = '%b %d\n%H:%M'`